# IE change event on file input

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, input

I am trying to fire a custom function when a  gets changed.
I'm triggering the input through a button(which has custom styling).
When the input is triggered by the button, the change event doesn't fire, however if I click the "browse" button of the input the event fires properly.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Note: I am using delegate since the input gets added dynamically.

Here's my setup:

```
$("#parent")
.delegate(".browse","click",function(){
    $(this).siblings("input[type='file']").trigger("click");
})
.delegate("input[type='file']","change",function(e){
    alert("changed");
})
```

Here's also a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/np88n/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#parent")
.delegate(".browse","click",function(){
    $(this).siblings("input[type='file']").trigger("click");
})
```

change in

```
 $("#parent")
    .delegate(".browse","click",function(){
        $(this).siblings("input[type='file']").trigger("change");
    })
```

Comment: this triggers the change event before the user has selected a file